# Eclipse Headless Application failing with Stackoverflow error

Tags: eclipse

I have built up an eclipse headless application, but while running it ends up with Stackoverflow error.

```
!SESSION 2020-06-24 16:24:05.556 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_251
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -application com.headless.application indir C:\workspace\TestData
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -application com.headless.application -consoleLog indir C:\workspace\TestData

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-06-24 18:43:21.315
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.BinaryResourceImpl$EObjectOutputStream.saveEObject(BinaryResourceImpl.java:1236)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.BinaryResourceImpl$EObjectOutputStream.saveEObjects(BinaryResourceImpl.java:1003)
```

Perhaps I thought this is because of memory issues so I tried to increase the memory in eclipse.ini file:

```
-vmargs
-Xmx16G
-Xms3G
-Xss16M
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=50
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=60
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

But still it fails with same Stackoverflow error.

I'm running my headless eclipse application via a batch file. The content of batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
start eclipse -application com.headless.application -consoleLog indir C:\workspace\TestData
```

So my first doubt is that whether my headless application is considering the eclipse.ini file or not? If not what are other ways to pass eclipse.ini file directly in above eclipse call?

In case if it is considering the eclipse.ini file, what other options can be tried?

**Note:** In case of same GUI application, it is working fine.

Comment: In most cases StackOverflowError is caused by a programming error rather than just a memory issue. Look at the full stack trace to see why the stack has got so big.

Comment: If adding `-Xinvalide` does not prevent the application from starting, something is wrong with your `eclipse.ini` (please show the whole file in this case). Otherwise, it is probably a bug in the application causing the allocation of infinite memory.

Comment: I tried adding -Xinvalide, application starts normally with it. In my question I have added exact content of eclipse.ini file.

Comment: Is it considering eclipse.ini file? Is there a way to pass this file with headless application call?